# How to fix vulnerabilities of installed package

Tags: react-native, npm, react-native-elements

I tried this

```
 npm install react-native-elements
```

I got

```
found 454 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I tried this

```
npm audit fix
```

and I got

```
fixed 396 of 454 vulnerabilities in 38064 scanned packages
  58 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated
```

I tried

```
npm uninstall react-native-elements
```

But this works as npm install react-native-elements somehow.

Should I concern this 58 vulnerabilities ? Can I fix this manually ?
If it is difficult to fix, How I can delete this package correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete the package correctly, try removing it from `package.json` and then try `npm install`.

However, you should not worry about vulnerabilities.